# make command for installing OpenSSH on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, openssh, make

I am currently trying to compile OpenSSH on Ubuntu. 
I am following the steps below which I got from the openssh website;
(ref: http://www.openssh.com/openbsd.html)

OpenSSH 6.2: March 22, 2013
ftp://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/openssh-6.2.tar.gz

```
# cd /usr/src/usr.bin
# tar xvfz …/openssh-6.2.tar.gz
# cd ssh
# make obj    ←--------------------  error message
# make cleandir
# make depend
# make
# make install
# cp ssh_config sshd_config /etc/ssh
```

and restart sshd.

I am having the error message below when I reached the command `make obj`.

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/bin/ssh# make obj
Makefile:3: *** missing separator.  Stop.
root@ubuntu:/usr/bin/ssh#
```

Can anyone please guide me if you can and let me know how I can compile the source code and run it?
I have a project where I need to change a config in the source code of openssh, this is the reason why I want to know how to compile and run the source code properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have downloaded the wrong version, and you are looking at the wrong directions.  You can't build the **BSD** version on Linux, you need the portable version.

- http://www.openssh.org/portable.html
- ftp://ftp.ca.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/INSTALL

Comment: thanks, I followed the steps and installed zlib and OpenSSL.
 I am having the error message while trying to compile and install openssh: 
root@ubuntu:/usr/src/openssh-5.0p1# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
root@ubuntu:/usr/src/openssh-5.0p1# make install
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
root@ubuntu:/usr/src/openssh-5.0p1# make install
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
root@ubuntu:/usr/src/openssh-5.0p1# 
can you please help..